# How can I check if a node references a Drupal Commerce product?

Tags: commerce

Is there a short function in Drupal Commerce API that returns TRUE (or something else) if a given node references a product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a short function, though that's not a bad idea for a feature request. However, it's not that difficult using the Field Info API to determine if a given node contains a product reference field. One method would be using [field_info_instances()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7).

With this function and your node object, you can retrieve an array of all field instances on your node with the following code:

```
$instances = field_info_instances('node', $node->type);
```

You would then need to loop over the returned instances and use `field_info_field($instance['field_name'])` to load the field info array and see if the type of any given field is commerce_product_reference. If so, then you know the node can *at least* refer to a product... but that doesn't mean a reference is actually established.

For that you'd need to make sure the node contained data for that instance. That could be as simple as checking `if (!empty($node->$instance_name))`, but it'll depend on how you're actually building / using these reference fields.

One simpler way to find if a product reference instance is on the node is possible if you know your reference field's name. For that you can use [field_read_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_read_instance/7) with the following code to return the info array of the instance or FALSE if it doesn't exist for the given node type:

```
$instance = field_read_instance('node', $field_name, $node->type);
```

Hope those help, and feel free to open an issue in the [Commerce issue tracker](http://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce) for any related helper functions under the "Developer experience" component. I suggest you spend time getting to know the Field Info / CRUD APIs, as they'll be very helpful to you in your Drupal 7 development.

Comment: Has there been a function added since to provide this functionality? I see there's a filter in Views, but I'm having trouble finding a corresponding PHP method.